# python regex to calculate vowel/consonant ratio in English

Tags: python, regex

I've embarked on a reasonably dumb linguistics project to learn regular expressions in Python. I'm pretty sure I could avoid the multiple passes over the same string, and find a more "compact" and "pythonic" way to do what I'm trying to do, which is: calculate using regex whether 'Y|y' in a word is a vowel or a consonant. At the bottom of the code segment, I've put in a comment block 20 words containing 12 vowel y's and 9 consonant y's. Seems like the code could be simplified and the re.compile lines merged together.

```
import re
vowelRegex = re.compile(r'[aeiouAEIOU]')
consoRegex = re.compile(r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-xzB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]')
yconsRegex = re.compile(r'[aeiou]y[aeiou]') 
ycon2Regex = re.compile(r'\bY')
yVowlRegex = re.compile(r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-xzB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]y[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]') 
yVow2Regex = re.compile(r'y\b')

#thestring = 'Sky Family Yurt Germany Crypt Day New York Pennsylvania Myth Hungry Yolk Year Bayou Yak Silly Beyond Dynamite Mystery Yacht Yoda'
#thestring = 'Crypt Pennsylva Myth Dynamite Mystery'
#thestring='RoboCop eats baby food. Pennsylvania Baby Food in the bayou. And, New York is where I\'d Rather be!'
thestring='violent irrational intolerant allied to racism and ' \
    'tribalism bigotry invested in ignorance and hostile to free '\
    'inquiry contemptuous of women and coercive towards children ' \
    'organized religion ought to have a great deal on its conscience ' \
    'Yak yacht beyond mystery'
fun=vowelRegex.findall(thestring)
nofun=consoRegex.findall(thestring)
funny = yVowlRegex.findall(thestring) 
foony = []
for f in funny:
    foony.append (f[1])
fun += foony   
fun += yVow2Regex.findall(thestring)
notfunny = yconsRegex.findall(thestring)

foony = []
for f in notfunny:
    foony.append (f[1])
nofun += foony
nofun += ycon2Regex.findall(thestring)

print(thestring)
print('Vowels:',''.join(fun), len(''.join(fun)))
print('Consos:',''.join(nofun), len(''.join(nofun)))


'''
Sky         Vowel; endswith 1
Family      Vowel; endswith 2 
Yurt        Consonant; begswith 1
Germany     Vowel; endswith 3
Crypt       Vowel; sandwiched 1
Day         Vowel; endswith 4
New York    Consonant; begswith 2
Pennsylva   Vowel; sandwiched 2
Myth        Vowel; sandwiched 3
Hungry      Vowel; endswith 5
Yolk        Consonant; begswith 3
Year        Consonant; begswith 4
Bayou       Consonanwich 1
Yak         Consonant; begswith 5
Silly       Vowel; endswith 6
Beyond      Consonanwich 2
Dynamite    Vowel; sandwiched 4
Mystery     Vowel; sandwiched, Vowel; endswith!
Yacht       Consonant; begswith 6
Yoda        Consonant; begswith 7
'''
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How do I simplify and streamline this code and make it more "pythonic?"

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into to the question (as explained in the [site guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and [sample code guidelines](/help/mcve)), rather than leaving [comments](/help/privileges/comment) or [linking](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527) to them. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: That said, the question as asked is too broad to be [on-topic](/help/on-topic) for SO. However, it'd be good for [CodeReview.SE]. SO is more for non-working code, or perhaps specific optimizations, rather than general improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an or operator in regex, that could reduce it a bit. For example:

```
yVowlRegex = re.compile(r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-xzB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]y[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]|y\b')
```

now includes both yVowl and yVow2

Comment: That doesn't quite work, although it's good info to know that you can "stack" the re.compile statements, but apparently only works if findall is searching for the same # of chars in a pattern. Otherwise you have to make two passes. This is because 'y' can be a consonant if surrounded by two vowels (3-char pattern), or a vowel if surrounded by two consonants (3-char), or a vowel if final letter in a word boundary (1-char pattern).

Comment: Ah true, I don't claim to be an expert but you can pretty much account for all patterns with the OR statement as long as they are exclusive conditions. I thought that pattern would work as it would pick up:
larry <- vowel cypress <- vowel but not eyes <- consonant

https://regexr.com/ play around with this site if you want to learn more about regex, it is a super useful tool.

Comment: Thanks again @joshua-lewis! I have also tried [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) but it can be unreadable at some screen resolutions (very busy screens).

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua-Lewis answer led me to the following way to streamline the code above:

```
import re
vowelRegex = re.compile(r'[aeiouAEIOU]|[b-df-hj-np-tv-xzB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]y[b-df-hj-np-tv-xz]|y\b')
consoRegex = re.compile(r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-xzB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XZ]|[aeiou]y[aeiou]|\bY')
vowelRescan = re.compile(r'[aeiouyAEIOUY]')
consoRescan = re.compile(r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-xyzB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-XYZ]')
thestring='any and every religion is violent irrational intolerant '\
    'allied to racism and tribalism bigotry invested in ignorance and '\
    'hostile to free inquiry contemptuous of women and coercive towards '\
    'children organized religion ought to have a great deal on its '\
    'conscience why it continues toward the 22nd century ACE is a mystery '\
    'known only to New Yorkers and lovers of the bayou'
fun=vowelRegex.findall(thestring)
funn=''.join(fun)
fun = ''.join(vowelRescan.findall(funn))
nofun=consoRegex.findall(thestring)
nofunn=''.join(nofun)
nofun=''.join(consoRescan.findall(nofunn))

print(thestring)
print('Vowels:',fun, len(fun))
print('Consos:',nofun, len(nofun))



'''
Sky         Vowel; endswith 1
Family      Vowel; endswith 2 
Yurt        Consonant; begswith 1
Germany     Vowel; endswith 3
Crypt       Vowel; sandwiched 1
Day         Vowel; endswith 4
New York    Consonant; begswith 2
Pennsylva   Vowel; sandwiched 2
Myth        Vowel; sandwiched 3
Hungry      Vowel; endswith 5
Yolk        Consonant; begswith 3
Year        Consonant; begswith 4
Bayou       Consonanwich 1
Yak         Consonant; begswith 5
Silly       Vowel; endswith 6
Beyond      Consonanwich 2
Dynamite    Vowel; sandwiched 4
Mystery     Vowel; sandwiched, Vowel; endswith!
Yacht       Consonant; begswith 6
Yoda        Consonant; begswith 7
'''
```